# google sheets script only applies to a specific range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to input timestamps into a dashboard like layout and need the script to only insert timestamps in a specific range

i have this code from [Here](https://yagisanatode.com/2018/02/21/add-the-current-date-to-a-sheet-when-data-is-added-so-that-the-date-does-not-changestatic-google-sheets/)

```
* Creates a Date Stamp if a column is edited.
*/

//CORE VARIABLES
// The column you want to check if something is entered.
var COLUMNTOCHECK = 4;
// Where you want the date time stamp offset from the input location. [row, column]
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,1];
// Sheet you are working on
var SHEETNAME = 'Cover Page'

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //checks that we're on the correct sheet.
  if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) { 
    var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    //checks the column to ensure it is on the one we want to cause the date to appear.  
    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) { 
      var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
  }
}
```

i need it only to apply to E12:E19

Any help would be wonderful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the script you have with

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
if (sheet.getName() == 'Cover Page' && e.range.columnStart === 5 && e.range.rowStart > 11 && e.range.rowStart < 20) {
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date());
    }
}
```

and see if that works?